# Prove or disprove the statement: A ∩ (B ∪ C) = (A ∩ B ) ∪ C. How to show that x exists in all the sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I think that this statement is true. I wanted to use set notation to prove this statement. My steps that I took so far are:

1). Show that x is an element in the sets on the left,

x ∈ A ∩ (B ∪ C), x ∈ (B ∪ C)

2). Show that x is an element in the sets on the right.

I used the distributive law to rewrite (A ∩ B) ∪ C to (C ∪ A) ∩ (B ∪ C).

x ∈ (C ∪ A), x ∈ (B ∪ C)

After this, I'm not too sure what step to take next?

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram. That is always the first step.

Comment: You are completely wrong. Yor statement is FALSE. Take $A=\mathbf Z^-, B=\{0\}$ and $C=\mathbf Z^+$ Then : $$(A\cap B)\cup C = \emptyset\cup\mathbf Z^-=\mathbf Z^-$$ while $$A\cap(B\cup C)=\emptyset$$.

Comment: Take C = B. Then LHS = $A \cap (B \cup B) = A \cap B$. RHS = $(A \cap B) \cup B = B$. So any case where $C = B$ and $A \cap B \neq B$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @Neo: See AbhiramNatarajan's comment. Is the best answer.

Comment: If $A=\emptyset$ then the left side is $\emptyset$ and the right side is $C.$ Can you find a counterexample to $\emptyset=C?$

Answer (score 4):

It is *not* true. Take $A=B=\{0\}$ and $C=\{1\}$. Then$$A\cap(B\cup C)=\{0\}\text{ and }(A\cap B)\cup C=\{0,1\}.$$